# Tumblr: Adding content to a certain tag

Tags: tumblr

I want to add a line of code into a post with a certain tag and only that tag, I'm not sure how to go about that since I don't see any kind of class with each post.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: It could only be done with js as far as I can tell. You would detect if the tag exists at runtime and then use js to inject the code for you. If that is what you want I think it is possible.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you would not be able to do that by tag, because Tumblr doesn't associate individual tags with a class, but you could in theory do this for post type (Text, Photo, Quote, etc.)

Comment: This should be a comment to the original question, not a separate answer.